# iTerm2: Differentiate user input from computer output for better readability

Tags: terminal, iterm

When using iTerm, it gets confusing to understand what happened in previous commands, cause user input has the same formatting as the info output.

Is it possible to do something as below?

This is how it is today:

[image]

This is a simple solution that would make my life easier:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize your `PS1` variable in `~/.bash_profile` file. For example, this is mine:

```
export PS1='\[\e[32;1m\]\h:\[\e[31m\]\W \[\e[32;1m\]\u\[\e[0m\]\$ '
```

The tokens are:

```
\e[32;1m\]  - the color green
\h          - host name (i.e. the computer's name)
:           - the literal colon (:) character
\e[31m\]    - the color red
\W          - current working directory
\u          - user name
\e[0m\]     - the color black
\$          - normally display the dollar sign, change to # when logged in as root
```

[Reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt). Google for "ps1 prompt generator" for tools to help you configure it. This is what my prompt looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! It works for both terminal and iTerm, helped me a lot.